# The letter “v” etymologically corresponds to the letter “f”

Tags: etymology

Does the German language have any other etymologically connected words in which the letter "v" corresponds to the letter "f", e.g.

vor/Fürst/führen

Comment: Outside of loanwords, the letter *v* is just a variant of the letter *f* in German. You could mix v and f up and the text would be as readable as before. In fact, before the 1901 spelling harmonisation, many people did.

Comment: @Janka Thanks! Very useful answer.

Comment: But there are hundreds of such loanwords: *Variante, Video, Villa, Virus, Vision, Variation, Votum, Violine, Vulkan, Volumen, Visier, Veto, Visum, Vitamin, Vampier, Vandalismus, Venus, via, virtuell, vage, variabel, virtuos, visuell, votieren, vakant, ...* Und das waren nur Beispiele für häufig verwendete Wörter, die mit V beginnen. Es gibt noch viel mehr, bei denen das V im inneren des Wortes wie W ausgesprochen wird (*evangelisch, eventuell, Event, Eva, oval, ...) Ich kann derzeit sogar kein einziges Wort finden, das als 2. Buchstaben ein v hat das wie f ausgesprochen wird.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast, Duden schreibt zu evangelisch:  [evaŋˈɡeː…], auch: [efaŋ…]. Und zu Eva: [ˈeːfa], auch: [ˈeːva].

Comment: @prostorech: Please, make clear what you want to ask. The title is not a question. The question refers with "any other" to an unknown reference word (I ask you: Any other than what?!). The pattern "vor/Fürst/führen" is not clear to me at all. I voted -1 and want to close this question.

Answer (score 1):

The only other example the consulted dictionaries are providing is:

- *voll* 'full' - *Fülle* 'fullness, welter'

And it looks like as this is the only other example of the *v*-*f*-alternation within a German word-family (like your *vor* - *Fürst*). However, you have to keep in mind, that these rules for using *v* or *f* in certain words are a product of "modern" spelling regulations and have nothing to do with their pronunciation.

--- A quick note on your example: The verb *führen* is etymologically not connected to *vor* or *Fürst*.